# How to cut a substring from a formated string in python?

Tags: python, string

The string is formated as `'[DATE] record flag: X1.X2.X3.X4.YEAR.NUM;'`, where `DATA` is a date string; there is **one or two spaces** between `:` and `X1`; `X1`, `X2`, `X4` are composed of **one or more chars**; X3 consisits of **zero or more chars**; `YEAR` and `NUM` are **4 and 3 digits**, respectively.

Here is an exmaple: `s = '[2011-03-13] record flag: NW.SENSOR..MH1.2011.012;'`

How do I cut `'NW'` and `'SENSOR'` from `s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.split`:

```
>>> s = '[2011-03-13] record flag: NW.SENSOR..MH1.2011.012;'

>>> s.split(' ')[3].split('.')
['NW', 'SENSOR', '', 'MH1', '2011', '012;']

>>> out = s.split(' ')[3].split('.')

>>> out[0]
'NW'

>>> out[1]
'SENSOR'
```

---

Using `re.search`:

```
>>> s = '[2011-03-13] record flag: NW.SENSOR..MH1.2011.012;'

>>> out = re.search(r':\s+([^.]+)\.([^.]+)', s)

>>> out.group(1)
'NW'

>>> out.group(2)
'SENSOR'
```

Comment: peferct, I like the `re` solution. but btw, why add `r` before the pattern since without it the expression also gives good results?

Comment: @Lee No, `r` stands for raw. Its there so that the Python takes the string as raw and pass it as it is to Regex without any internal manipulation..

Answer (score 1):

Use some splitting and stripping:

```
parts = s.split(":")[1].strip().split(".")
parts[0] # Should be NW
parts[1] # Should be SENSOR
```